# how to use gt table move groups to column?

Tags: r, gt

I am making summary tables using the gt package. I want to simplify the output a little and make the time points displayed as columns instead of rows. Right now I have each point as a separate row like:

| Label | estimate | p value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| case time 1 | xx | xx |
| control time 1 | xx | xx |
| case time 2 | xx | xx |
| control time 2 | xx | xx |

I am hoping to organize it more like this:

| Label | time 1 |  | time 2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | estimate | p-value | estimate | p-value |
| case | xx | xx | xx | xx |
| control | xx | xx | xx | xx |

I have variables 'case_control' which is just the case and control assignment and 'time' which is the time points

```
rbind(H_LG3, W_LG3) %>%
gt()%>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = everything(),
    decimals = 3)%>%
    tab_row_group(group = md('**H**'), rows = 1:nrow(H_LG3)) %>%
    tab_row_group(group = md('**W**'), rows = (nrow(H_LG3) + 1):(nrow(H_LG3) + nrow(W_LG3))%>%
  cols_label(
    label=md("**Label**"),
    estimate_ci=md("**Estimate(CI)**"),
    formatted_p_value=md("**P Value**")
  )%>%
  tab_header(md("**Table 4**"))
```

I am also merging two tables  in this step but they are just being stacked vertically and labelled. The columns are 'label' 'estimate_ci' 'p_val' 'time' and 'case_control'

Comment: Try with reshaping your data using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_wider`  before passing it to `gt()`. Afterwards you can use `tab_spanner()`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of `rbind(H_LG3, W_LG3)` best shared using `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyselect)
library(gt)

df <- tribble(
  ~label, ~estimate, ~p_value,
  "case time 1", 4, 21,
  "control time 1", 5, 22,
  "case time 2", 6, 23,
  "control time 2", 7, 24
)

df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(label, delim = " time ", names = c("label", "time")) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = time,
    values_from = c(estimate, p_value),
    names_glue = "time{time},{.value}"
  ) %>%
  select(sort(peek_vars())) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner_delim(delim = ",")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-28 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>